# Magento 2:- How to get customers now online?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, database, customer

Magento 2:- How to get customers now online?

Want to get all customers data **current login**.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can view this information from the store admin **Customer > Now Online**

If you would like to retrieve the online customers from your custom programming knowledge from the database, there are two tables store this information. They are:

- customer_visitor
- customer_log

In this, customer_log table is especially for customer and customer_visitor is for anonymous user/visitor.

Please check these tables and let me know if this helps. Please accept my answer and upvote if you find it useful.

Thank you.

Comment: I glad you had it working. Please upvote my answer if it helped you in any way. Otherwise, just let it go.

Answer (score 0):

i think you get this via magento admin
Logged in admin

**Go to Customer > Click on Now online**

Comment: thanks for the reply,    Visiter Show not current login customer

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution.

```
public function getUserStatus(
        Post $post
    ) {

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $entity_id=$post->getEntityId();

        $values = $connection->fetchAll('SELECT  * FROM `customer_log` LEFT JOIN`customer_visitor` ON `customer_log`.`customer_id` = `customer_visitor`.`customer_id` WHERE customer_log.customer_id="'.$entity_id.'" ORDER BY `customer_visitor`.`last_visit_at` DESC');

       if($values){
          $this->lastLoginTime = $values[0]['last_login_at'];
           $this->lastLogoutTime = $values[0]['last_logout_at'];
           $this->lastVisitTime = $values[0]['last_visit_at'];

       }


        if (!$this->lastLoginTime) {


            return false;
        }




        if ($this->lastLogoutTime && strtotime( $this->lastLogoutTime) > strtotime( $this->lastLoginTime)) {


            return false;
        }

        // Predefined interval has passed since customer's last activity.
        $interval = $this->getOnlineMinutesInterval();
        $currentTimestamp = (new \DateTime())->getTimestamp();


        if ($this->lastVisitTime && $currentTimestamp - strtotime($this->lastVisitTime) > $interval * 60) {


            return false;
        }

        return True;


    }
```

template page

```
 <?php if($block->getUserStatus($post)) { ?>
                <div class="active-user">online</div>
            <?php }?>
```